# Custom error page not opening as model dialog box

Tags: event-receivers

I have created a customErrorPage for event receiver on ItemDeleting

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties) 
{
base.ItemDeleting(properties); 

    properties.Cancel = true; 
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl; 
    properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/EventReceiverProject1/CustomErrorPage.aspx
}
```

}

The issue is, it redirects me to the customErrorPage but does not open the page as Model Dialog Box. It opens with top and left navigation. how can I open the custom page as model window?

Comment: If you just want to get rid if the header and left nav you can add ?isDlg=1 to the end of your RedirectUrl

Comment: I tried the same. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with calling JavaScript from your event receiver something like this:

```
properties.RedirectUrl = "javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('/_layouts/EventReceiverProject1/CustomErrorPage.aspx')";
```

P.S. You can use `isDlg=1` like `/_layouts/EventReceiverProject1/CustomErrorPage.aspx?isDlg=1` but then chrome will be turned off.

Comment: do I need to add code to register the script? ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), ClientID, script, true);

Comment: Yes, you can register the script using `RegisterClientScriptBlock`